# C++ what type should I use if I know the exact type from a few possible?

Tags: c++, opengl, casting, type-conversion

hope you'll help me to understand.
I have a class, that defines a buffer:

```
typedef std::variant<signed char, unsigned char, short, unsigned short, int, unsigned int, float> BufferData;

struct BufferAttribute {
  unsigned int index;
  int size = 4;
  char format = ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT::FLOAT;
  bool normalized = false;
  int stride = 0;
  int offset = 0;
  std::vector<BufferData> data;
  std::string name;
};
```

As you can see, I have a **char** that defines a format, so in the future, I will know the exact data format.
But as for the data, I'm using a **variant** which makes me worry about the performance of the visitor.
What type can I use to make it faster or better? Or do you think that **Variant** is a good choice?

---

P.S. I worrying about processing thousands of numbers from this buffer in real-time in my game app.

Comment: If you have the format already attached to it, why not just use a union?

Comment: I thought that variant kinda faster, isn't it?

Comment: @СергейШарпов The main advantage of `std::variant` is type safety. I guess it's even a bit slower then a tuple.

Comment: @churill got it, thanks.

Comment: @СергейШарпов Unlike variant, union is not foolproofed, that makes it as fast as it gets.

Comment: I'm assuming that all the data in one buffer is the same... so using a `std::variant<std::vector<signed char>, std::vector<unsigned char>, ...>` would make more sense to me.

Comment: @super it's true, I like your way, it would be easier to get a correct buffer once than cast each buffer member all the time.
Thank you.

Comment: I agree with @super : you probably need a variant of vectors rather than a vector of variant. Maybe you need a variant of pairs<vector<actual data>; format>.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about performance, you have to measure it in your use case. General statements wrt. performance tend to be wrong or may out date with the next compiler version and or hardware generation.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726401/stdvariant-vs-inheritance-vs-other-ways-performance) the general performance of std::variant has been analyzed.

If this is applicable to you is in question. You have to make sure that the ´std::variant´ in `BufferAttribute` actually is your hotspot. You can find the hotspots using a tool such as `perf` or `vTune`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll get in touch with these tools.