# C++ Visitor Pattern overload

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, visitor-pattern

I have spent the past hours trying to find an elegant solution but however i am unable to.

Description: I would like to have a default implementation for a visitor functor in class visitor_base_all and then each of the derived classes for example visitor_override would define the method just for what it needs. I understand that this does not work because the operator() is not passed to the derived classes (due to C++ not overload across scopes which is fair enough), so the question is how to do this exactly?
I was thinking of doing it with overloaded lambdas or having a switch in the virtual base_class method and then each derived class overloading only the virtual methods called in that switch.

Regarding the lambdas, I am not sure on how to do it.
I have read the following before: [pablo_arias](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/06/26/std-variant/) [arne-mertz](https://arne-mertz.de/2018/05/overload-build-a-variant-visitor-on-the-fly/) and [stack_overflow_question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383563/is-there-any-hope-to-call-a-common-base-class-method-on-a-stdvariant-efficient) but i am still a bit confused on what would be the proper correct way forward.

Thank you for your time

**Short question:** Proper c++17 way of making below compile/work. What is the proper way to generalize it for a big number of derived types in the variant and derived classes?

**(Post comments-edit)** My problem is more generalized for a big number of classes and a lot more types, so if possible i would prefer to template/generalize it somehow. Below is the example with just 1 derived class, but what would be a proper way with having 10 classes? (I wouldn't want to declare using in each of them if it can be avoided).

```
#include <variant>

struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};
using type_x = std::variant<A,B,C>;

class base_class
{
protected:
    struct visitor_base_all
    {
        void operator()(const A& a){std::cout<<"A_base" << std::endl;}
        void operator()(const B& b){std::cout<<"B_base" << std::endl;}
        void operator()(const C& c){std::cout<<"C_base" << std::endl;}
    };
    virtual void run(type_x evt){return std::visit(visitor_base_all{}, evt);}
};

class derived_class :public base_class
{
    struct visitor_override : public visitor_base_all
    {
        void operator()(const C& c){};
    };
     virtual void run(type_x evt){return std::visit(visitor_override{}, evt);}
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] on which solutions might be based?

Comment: I think you want to explore the using declaration. `using visitor_base_all::operator();` inside visitor_override should do the trick.

Comment: @Barry: Even if `using` is the solution in both cases, OP's issue is not an issue with multiple base classes, but hiding member methods... Not the more appropriated duplicates IMO.

Comment: Hmm. @Barry it’s not immediately obvious to me how this is a duplicate (this question is about visitors, the other one about multiple inheritance … there isn’t much overlap at first sight), or how the linked answers answer this question.

Comment: @Jarod42 you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/originals/58610727/edit) the duplicate resolution, add another duplicate question, and/or remove an inappropriate one.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's exactly a duplicate. The reason OP's code doesn't work is because we're not merging across two different scopes, and you need a `using` declaration to bring in the other names. The fact that this case is specifically about visitors is not relevant.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the dupe *question* is not too similar, but its *answer* is a perfectly good one for this Q too. You can add other dupes if you find a more appropriate one (there's a lot of those).

Comment: In this case, it's once we find a name in the derived we don't continue looking in the base... instead of if we find a name in different bases, we don't consider it. But it's the same fundamental principle (which is even cited in OP) with the same solution.

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be to make the `void operator()` virtual, and just override what you need. This is how the visitor pattern normally works. If you find yourself not needing it to be virtual, you are probably misusing the pattern.

Comment: I apologise, my question is not clear enough. I know how to solve the compilation problem, but my problem is that i have a lot of derived classes and a lot of cases and i wouldn't want to use using base::operator() in each of them as this would be very ugly.(even if i would have a macro for it, still ugly imo) Again, my bad and your comments are valid. would it be ok if i edit the question a bit? Based on the edits i would say that it is no longer a duplicate?

Comment: @eucristian: Do you have chaining of derived classes? one which implement `operator()` for `A` another for `B` and a last one for `C`, or is it just default or provided?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, exactly. but i saw in one of Barry's duplicate the collector template. now sure how to implement it exactly though. trying now

Comment: Are you looking for something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28aac2c9b161883c)

Comment: yes. this is it.thank you very much mister Jarod@Jarod42

Comment: @Jarod42 would it be possible to do your example with variadic templates?

Comment: @eucristian: I would say yes with recursion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201565/discussion-between-eucristian-and-jarod42).